# Postgres not returning data on array_agg query as below

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The problem arise when there are no data for books in specific library. Consider a following working scenario.

Table name: **library**

```
--------------------------------
| id |    name     |    owner  |
--------------------------------
|  1 |     ABC     |     A     |
|  2 |     DEF     |     D     |
|  3 |     GHI     |     G     |
--------------------------------
```

Table name: **books**

```
--------------------------------
| id |    title    |  library  |
--------------------------------
|  a |     xxx     |     1     |
|  b |     yyy     |     1     |
|  c |     zzz     |     2     |
--------------------------------
```

Now when I do query like below:

```
SELECT library.name, array_agg(b.title) AS book_list FROM library, 
(SELECT title FROM books WHERE books.library = :library_no) as b 
WHERE library.id = :library_no GROUP BY library.id
```

The query generates output for library 1 & 2, but not for library 3. Why and how to solve this issue? (Generate an empty list on no library books)

Required Output:

```
----------------------
| name |    book_list |
----------------------
|  GHI |      {}      |   # or {null}
-----------------------
```

PS: I've even tried coalesce as below:

```
SELECT library.name, coalesce(array_agg(b.title), ARRAY[]::VARCHAR[]) AS book_list FROM library, 
(SELECT title FROM books WHERE books.library = :library_no) as b 
WHERE library.id = :library_no GROUP BY library.id
```

Postgres version: 12

Comment: Please add the desired output by editing the question

Comment: Here you go @AkhileshMishra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use left join for this kind of scenarios like below:

```sql
select 
    l.name, 
    array_agg(b.title) 
from library l left join books b on l.id=b.library
where l.id=3      -- here you can pass you library ID using :library_no variable
group by l.name
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=66c79162feb4ab5fe97639d39ca403bb)

Comment: Yes it works. but shouldn't `coalesce` return an empty array when there is no data?

Comment: it will return `{NULL}`. if you will use `coalesce` then it will return `{""}`. actually `{NULL}` and `{}` is same.

Comment: But in my case, no column is returned in case of coalesce also

Comment: what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: The problem is solved using your solution. but couldn't the problem solved with coalesce as above 'PS'